# App Details submission rejected "...remove this integration as a listed platform in the dev app."

Tags: facebook

I submitted my app details on Facebook, and received the following notice:

> Your app's main functionality lives off canvas. Please either choose
>   to host your app on canvas or remove this integration as a listed
>   platform in the dev app.

What integration platform is this referring to? Is it the `App on Facebook` integration that I have checked on the Basic app details page?

Comment: I believe this is due to what you filled on on the Basic App Details page.

Answer (score 3):

To check your settings, go to http://developers.facebook.com, click on "Apps" in the blue menu up top, click on your app in the left-navigation, click on "Edit Settings" in the Settings section. Scroll down to the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section.

If you have selected Canvas, a green checkbox will appear next to "App on Facebook". Make sure that "App on Facebook" is NOT selected unless you are actually building a Canvas app.

What is a Canvas app? For more information, consult the Facebook documentation on Canvas apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Comment: I have built a canvas app. Is it because the content loaded into the canvas is loaded from an external URL? Do I need to somehow host my canvas content on Facebook?

Comment: I figured out the issue: I had some images that were being pulled in from a non-https source.